# Microsoft Sharepoint list - Extract the difference between two dates INCLUDING years

Tags: list, sharepoint, office365

need help calculating a field that extracts the difference between two dates, i need the number of months considering the years.
Example: StartDate = 1/1/2019 EndDate = 2/1/2021
I have tried the function: =DATEDIF([Date 1],[Date 2],"ym")
However it ignores the years and shows 1 month instead of 25 months

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use below formula in the calculated column.

=DATEDIF(date1,date2,"M")

[image]